# Why is this JSONP feed throwing "Unexpected Token" error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I'm trying to grap [this remote JSONP feed](http://calvaryslo.onthecity.org/plaza/%2aevents%2a?format=json) via jQuery.

Every time I try, I get an error of "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (" or similar.

Am I doing something wrong or is something in the JSONP data formatted/escaped incorrectly?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/callmeed/d3tSX/2/

```
var _event_url = "http://calvaryslo.onthecity.org/plaza/*events*?format=json";
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: _event_url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg.length);
    }
});​
```

Comment: This url returns data in JSON format, not JSONP

Comment: Do you have control over the output on that page, or is it a third party API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this feed returns JSON, not a javascript function call:

```
[{Query172031345640518702567_1334079878875({...
```

But it should be:

```
Query172031345640518702567_1334079878875({...
```

I don't know if this service is under your control and you can changed it, or you just need to add some params to the URL (check the manual).

Also the content type of the response should be `application/javascript`, not `text/json`.

Comment: Yeah, it was indeed that. I don't control the service and those that do admitted it was not structured properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `dataType: 'jsonp'` JQuery appends a `callback` url parameter to the request. The value of this parameter must be the function name of the callback function the server returns. As Eugene Retunsky already mentioned this is formatted incorrectly, also it seems that the server code is omitting the first character of the function name so `jQuery_674...` becomes `Query_674...` which will not work.