# Error JSONP Store

Tags: jsonp, sencha-touch-2

I am retrieving information for a List via JSONP and am getting the following error in console browser: "unexpected token : "

My store:

```
Ext.define ('Projeto.store.Mural', {
 extend 'Ext.data.Store'
 requires: [
     'Projeto.model.Mural'
 ]

 config: {
     autoLoad: true,
     model: 'Projeto.model.Mural'
     storeId 'MuralStore'
     Proxy {
         type: 'jsonp'
         url: 'http://URL/mural'
         reader: {
             type: 'json',
             rootProperty: 'rows'
         }
     }
 }
});
```

My List:

```
Ext.define ('Projeto.view.MuralList', {
 extend 'Ext.dataview.List'
 alias: 'widget.murallist'

 config: {
     loadingText: 'Loading ...',
     store: 'MuralStore'
     itemTpl: [
         '<div> Message: {message} </ div>
     ]
 }
 });
```

JSON returns my URL:

```
{
 "rows": [
     {
         "lookup": "yyyy"
         "dateTime", "10/10/1970"
         "id": "1",
         "message": "yyyy"
     }
     {
         "lookup": "dsdfasfsadf"
         "dateTime", "15/05/2012"
         "id": "2",
         "message": "dsdfasfsadf"
     }
 ]
 }
```

Does anyone know why the error, because JSON is in a valid format.

Thank you.

Comment: The value for itemTpl: is missing a closing quote, is that a typo or how it really looks?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma in the middle :

```
{
 "rows": [
     {
         "lookup": "yyyy"
         "dateTime", "10/10/1970"
         "id": "1",
         "message": "yyyy"
     },
     {
         "lookup": "dsdfasfsadf"
         "dateTime", "15/05/2012"
         "id": "2",
         "message": "dsdfasfsadf"
     }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited the file before you can post and inadvertently removed the commas. It is spelled with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the service you're accessing returns JSON but **not** JSONP.  Search the jsonp tag for "unexpected token".  You'll find e.g. [Why is this JSONP feed throwing "Unexpected Token" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10093697/1211981)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You'r missing `':'` at many places and also `','` at the end of statements. It always good practise to use `:` before the property value and `,` at the end of statement.

Like this,

```
 ...  
 ...  
 requires: [
     'Projeto.model.Mural'
 ],

 config: {
     autoLoad: true,
     model: 'Projeto.model.Mural',
     storeId: 'MuralStore',
     proxy : {
        type:'jsonp',
     },
 ....
 ....
```

Secondly, this error is occuring because your response is **not a VALID** jsonp response.

When I checked on [jsonplint.com](http://jsonplint.com), it showed me this error

```
Invalid JSONP
No callback function defined
Improper or no closing
```

1. So, either you need to make sure that you have a *valid callback function defined.*
2. Otherwise, you could do one thing. Change the `type:'jsonp'` to `type:'ajax'` and that should resolve your problem without having to change anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are requesting it as **jsonp**, not just **json**, it expects your json to be enclosed in a callback function. Something like:

```
callback({
 "rows": [
     {
         "lookup": "yyyy"
         "dateTime", "10/10/1970"
         "id": "1",
         "message": "yyyy"
     }
     {
         "lookup": "dsdfasfsadf"
         "dateTime", "15/05/2012"
         "id": "2",
         "message": "dsdfasfsadf"
     }
 ]
 })
```