# missing ; before statement in API RESULT jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

i am calling API using JQUERY, and getting this error i don't know what is i am doing wrong. this is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Movie App</title>
    <script src="Jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            var Title, Desc, Rating, Rel_Date;
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"https://api.cinemalytics.com/v1/movie/id/e80b298d/?auth_token=***********************************",
                dataType:"jsonp",
                //datatype : "application/jsonp",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function(json){
                    //alert(json);
                    //$("#div1").append(json.id);
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
                }
            });
        });


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>Rating</td>
            <td>Release Date</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="div1"></div>
</body>
```

[image]

This is result I want.

```
{"Id":"e80b298d","ImdbId":"tt0248126","OriginalTitle":"Kabhi Khushi Kabhie Gham","Title":"Kabhi Khushi Kabhie Gham","Description":"Yash Raichand is a wealthy business man married to Naina Raichand and has two sons, Rahul and Rohan. Rahul was adopted since he was born. Rahul falls in love with a poor girl named Anjali but his dad forbids their love, for he has wanted him to marry his friend's daughter. Rahul marries Anjali, so his dad kicks him out of the house and moves to London with Anjali, Pooja (her young sister), and his nanny. Ten years later, Rahul and Anjali have a sum named Krish who is in forth grade. Rohan then graduates from boarding school and insists on reuniting the family together. Will he reunite them again?","TrailerLink":"","TrailerEmbedCode":"","Country":"IN","Region":"BOLLYWOOD","Genre":"Family","RatingCount":19,"Rating":4.1,"CensorRating":"U/A","ReleaseDate":"12/14/2001","Runtime":210,"Budget":400000000,"Revenue":1350000000,"PosterPath":"https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/cinemalytics/movie/DF7D2E5CB4EA9B4F1497A159383BADF5.jpg"}
```

**EDIT**

If I change Datatype to Json as suggested in other Answers I'm having following Error:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at.  (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: pls dont ***post auth_token*** try changing `dataType:"jsonp",` to `dataType:"json",`

Comment: if i change dataType:"jsonp", to dataType:"json" i am having this error.Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.cinemalytics.com/v1/movie/id/e80b298d/?auth_token=******. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: use your auth_token. i change it to `*`

Comment: i used my auth_token only but than too get an error,which i post in comment

Comment: Please somebody answer..........

Comment: Try again. I have fixed the APIs to support CORS now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that the API doesn't support JSONP. Set up an intermediary server to handle the API request then call your server via AJAX.

There are a lot of similar questions on SO about this; [such as this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365469/jquery-ajax-api-request-in-json-format-causes-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected?rq=1)